# Java GUI 101 - changing the title of a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

Simple question here. How do I change the title of a `JPanel`, for exmple

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/figures/uiswing/components/ConverterColored.png

change the text "converter" here to something else?

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT:** sorry, it was a `JPanel`!

Comment: See also the [tutorial and source code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/model.html) for the example.

Comment: read the code that produced the example, search for "Converter" and change it :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, the link you provided contains a [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) not [`JPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html).

Second, pass the title as a parameter to the [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) constructor once you create it [`JFrame(String title)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#JFrame%28java.lang.String%29):

```
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("My Title");
```

or use the method [`setTitle(String title)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setTitle%28java.lang.String%29) inherited from class [`Frame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html):

```
myFrame.setTitle("My Title");
```

Answer (score 6):

The element in the screen you linked to looks like a `JFrame`, and not a `JPanel`. The `setTitle()` method should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

It's not the `JPanel`, I think it will be the `JFrame` that you want to change, it has a `setTitle()` method you can use.
Also the constructor for the `JFrame` takes a string argument for it's title

Answer (score 3):

Or if you don't have access to the JFrame directly (or just want to do it in a neater, more portable fashion)

```
SwingUtilities.getRoot(this).setTitle("SomeTitle);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's *not* a JPanel. It's a `JFrame` that contains `JPanel`s.

The title can be set in the constructor, and can be changed with `setTitle()`

If you read the tutorial you're linking to, you'll note that there's a link to the "Converter" application. Further reading would take you to the source for that tutorial application:

[Converter application source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ConverterProject/src/components/Converter.java)

```
 //Create and set up the window.
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("Converter");
```

Comment: See also the [whole Converter Project](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#Converter).

Answer (score 1):

that would be a TitledBorder.
See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html